# Why Class keeps throwing 'The type initializer for 'MyClass' threw an exception.'

Tags: c#, asp.net

I copied and pasted the methods out of a class from one project and pasted it all into a class in another project. I have searched around and nothing has come up that pertains exactly or close to why in this case it would be throwing the error.

I made sure that the namespace matched the project, and it keeps throwing

> {"The type initializer for 'MyClass' threw an exception."}

So then I created another class and left it empty, and when I created an object of it, the page loaded without a problem.
As soon as I add..

```
private static string strCn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DDB"].ConnectionString;
private static SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(strCn);
```

it threw the error, but if I comment that out and just add a public variable and a private one and a method

```
public int mynum = 1;
private static int num2 = 2;
```

it runs fine, but any other time I have used

```
private static string strCn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DDB"].ConnectionString;
private static SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(strCn);
```

in any of my classes it runs fine. So what would be causing the issue? I even manually entered in the private sqlconnection and strCn it would cause an error. To no avail.

Comment: Please show the definition of the `MyClass` class

Comment: Doesn't this kind of exception usually has an inner exception attached to it?

Comment: @Crono1981, the inner exception {"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."}

Comment: @pmacnaughton, I meant that when I write this type of class in my other projects the static string and static sqlconnection never causes errors. All I did was created a new project and added a new class and copy and pasted the contents from a class in my other project that I would be using for this project. So the answer, I think is, no they are not in the same assembly.

Comment: Then this is the real exception you want to look at for information on what has gone wrong. Remember that in the future. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess based on the limited is that the line

```
private static string strCn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DDB"].ConnectionString;
```

is throwing the exception.

That could happen if there were no connection string named "DDB", so `ConnectionStrings["DDB"]` returns null, which you then try to dereference with `.ConnectionString`.

Try moving the initialization of `strCn` into a static constructor, breaking out the initialization steps, and stepping through in the debugger.

```
public static
{ // Set a breakpoint here, and see what value is assigned to cfg.
    var cfg = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DDB"];
    strCn = cfg.ConnectionString;
}
```

If this turns out to be the issue, I suggest you keep the static constructor so that you can verify that the connection string has a correct value and do appropriate error handling if not.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I checked my webconfig and looked at the string, it was reading DBB and not DDB. After that was changed, its works perfectly. I will admit, during my cutting and pasting, I never even thought to check my webconfig to make sure that the name was correct

Answer (score 2):

That is because the initialization of the `static` variables in your class failed.

Read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645758%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) about the problem and solution.

In fact the problem is that the order of initialization can't always be determined correctly, which means that it is possible that the `SqlConnection cn` is initialized first, which will cause a `NullReferenceException` because the `strCn` isn't filled in yet.

Comment: No, they are guaranteed to be initialized before first use.  From your link: `they are only constrained to occur before the references to those fields`

Answer (score 1):

[`ConnectionStringSettingsCollection.Item(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6t3b6f3.aspx) returns null if no connection with the given name is found, so

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DDB"].ConnectionString;
```

throws a `NullReferenceException`.

You need to fix your configuration to ensure the connection string exists.